# Loop multiple videos

Tags: ios, video

What is the best way to loop a number of videos, that are already on an iPad?

Either an app or a built in solution. The slideshow feature of the built in Photos app does not really work - it crops the video, and adds a gray border.

I have tried a number of apps for this purpose, none of which actually seem to do the job very well or at all.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the VLC app was the only decent solution I could find.